# Stored procedure with a cursor when called through hibernate, fails

Tags: hibernate, sybase

We are using hibernate as a ORM tool in our project. We have a scenario where we need to call a stored procedure. Now this stored procedure uses a cursor internally to go through a list of rules stored in the database table.

When we are iterating through the cursor, we check @@sqlstatus !=2. The sqlstatus will be 2 when the result set in the cursor in traversed completely.

When we directly execute the stored procedure using exec , it returns the result. Also it runs through java JDBC code too. But when we call through hibernate, it fails in condition check @@sqlstatus !=2, because somehow it finds the sqlstatus = 2. We tried few debugging statements in the stored procedure, when the stored procedure is called through hibernate, it will not traverse the resultset as sqlstatus = 2 and hence the stored procedure returns null.

We are using sybase ASE 15.7, hibernate 4.1 version.

Please let me know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is only natural that a cursor reaches @@sqlstatus = 2, since this indicates the end of the result set and typically a cursor is read until that condition occurs. Exactly why this happens in one scenario and not in another is not something anyone here will likely be able to figure out. There may be a difference in that the data is different (is there an open transaction in one of the scenarios?), or something else. Looks like you'll have to do some debugging of your SQL code.